# Why does Invoke-Sqlcmd throw a parser exception in Azure DevOps Pipelines but not locally?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The following script works locally, using the same connection details as the Azure DevOps pipeline

```
param ($server, $database, $username, $password, $script)

#
# Create the temporary file to contain the modified script
#
$newscript = Join-Path -Path (Split-Path -Path $script) -ChildPath ("fixed_" + (Split-Path -Path $script -Leaf));
Write-Output $newscript
Set-Content -Path $newscript -Value "" -Encoding 'utf8'

#
# Fetch the currently applied migrations
#
$migrationIds = ""
$qry = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$server" -Database "$database" -Username "$username" -Password "$password" -Query "SELECT DISTINCT [MigrationId] FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory]" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Write-Output($qry)
if ($null -ne $qry) {
    $migrationIds = ($qry | Select-Object -ExpandProperty MigrationId) -Join "|"
}

#
# Match the chunks in the script with the list of applied migrations, and comment them out
#
if ($migrationIds -ne "") {
    $regex = "(?ms)^IF NOT EXISTS\(SELECT \* FROM \[__EFMigrationsHistory\] WHERE \[MigrationId\] = N'(" + $migrationIds + ")'\).*?END;\s+GO"
    $c = (Get-Content $script -Raw) -replace $regex, "/*`r`n`$0`r`n*/";
    Set-Content -Path $newscript -Value $c -Encoding 'utf8'
}
else {
    Copy-Item $script $newscript
}
```

When it's run through an Azure DevOps pipeline, it throws a ParserException.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : 
At D:\a\1\s\devops\azure\ef-idempotent-fixer.ps1:14 char:8
+ $qry = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$server" -Database "$database"  ...
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

I've checked the variables being passed through from the pipeline all look OK, yet I can't see why this would be breaking in the pipeline.

**UPDATE 1:**

Appears the error relates to a connectivity issue with the Azure SQL Server.

Added the following to the PowerShell script to test connectivity, which does indeed fail in the pipeline. My guess is the firewall on SQL Server in Azure.

```
try
{
    $connString = "Data Source=$server;Database=$database;User ID=$username;Password=$password"

    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connString

    $conn.Open()
    if($conn.State -eq "Open")
    {
        Write-Host "Test connection successful"
        $conn.Close()
    }
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Test connection failed"
}
```

Comment: Looks like this is actually a connectivity issue, the error isn't very obvious though

Comment: The ParserException is often a red herring-style error message from Invoke-Sqlcmd. Are you sure there wasn't another error message just before it regarding network connectivity or login failures?

Comment: Unfortunately not. As the SQL server is in Azure, I'm guessing firewall rules are probably the reason why. Using the `SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1` task, you supply an Azure subscription and that adds a temporary firewall rule I believe. Initially I was using the standard `PowerShell@2` task, switched to `AzurePowerShell@5` and still no joy.

Comment: It could be interesting/useful to see the actual exception message from the failed `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`. e.g.: if it's defaulting to use `Named Pipes Provider` or `Shared Memory Provider` instead of the `TCP/IP Provider` you might be able to coax it using something like `Data Source=tcp:FullyQualifiedServerNameOrIpAddress,portNumber;`.

Comment: I ended up changing my approach to the problem in general, but I'm quite certain this was caused by firewall rules. The built in Azure Pipelines task for deploying SQL scripts adds & deletes a firewall rule (https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/SqlAzureDacpacDeploymentV1/DeploySqlAzure.ps1)